# Loading jquery within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using javascript to embed iframe, and I want to load jquery in the iframe. However, it doesn't work. Could you please give me any advice?

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.scrolling = 'no';
   iframe.frameBorder = 0;
   iframe.marginWidth = 0;
   iframe.marginHeight = 0;

var widget = "<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"

var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(widget);
doc.close();
})();
```

Comment: You have a quote issue. Same quotes within quotes must be escaped. I would just use different quotes. Actually, I would just put your jQuery script tag in your `<head>` along with another external JavaScript tag which you use `$(function(){ /* run your code here */ });` on... and I would avoid using `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`var widget = "<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"`

Has the problem that you are opening with `"` for the widget string, but you are also using double quotes inside that string. Change it to:

`var widget = "<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>"`

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I made it var widget = "<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>", but it still doesn't work...